# how to make $.when execute when one of JSON request fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm using the below code to get JSON from multiple urls. However, when one of the URL failed or get 404 response the function the execute doesn't work. I read the jquery doc and I know "then" should execute no matter one of the call has failed.

```
var data = {};
var calls = [];
for (var i in funcs) {
    calls.push(
        $.getJSON(base_url+i,
            (function(i) {
                return function(d) {
                    data[i] = d;
                };
            }(i)) 
        )
    );
}
$.when.apply($,calls).then(function() {
    do_something(data);
});
```

Comment: Do you need to control when all of the requests have ended or can it be for each single request?

Comment: no. I just want to get the array of collected data. so if there is no data in this url ignore. but most importantly here I want make  do_something(data); execute

Comment: If you want `do_something(data)` to run even if one of the AJAX calls fails, `$.when()` may not be the right method to use. It bails out (and rejects the promise it returned instead of resolving it) as soon as one of the calls fail.

Comment: @user2581550 Could you give a try to this script, please? http://jsfiddle.net/LnAxZ/ I hadn't been able to test any, any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand how to make the function wait before you do 'do_somthing(data)' . It would not work like that

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at `always` method. It will executed in [both cases](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/). 
For example:

```
$.when.apply($, calls).always(function() { 
    alert('Resolved or rejected'); 
});
```

In response to successful transaction, arguments are same as .done() (ie. a = data, b = jqXHR) and for failed transactions the arguments are same as .fail() (ie. a = jqXHR, b = errorThrown). [(c)](https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/49)

Answer (score 3):

> I read the jquery doc and I know "then" should execute no matter one of the call has failed.

Nope, the promise only gets fulfilled if *all* of the passed objects are fulfilled. If one of them fails, the result will get rejected.

> is there a way to make do_something(data); execute no matter if it failed or not.

You could use [`.always`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/):

```
// doSomething waits until all are fulfilled or one is rejected
$.when.apply($,calls).always(do_something);
```

Yet, you probably want to execute the callback when all `calls` are resolved (no matter if fulfilled or rejected) - like [`allSettled`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseallsettled) does in Q. With jQuery, you have to work around a little:

```
var calls = $.map(funcs, function(_, i) {
    var d = new $.Deferred;
    $.getJSON(base_url+i).done(function(r/*…*/) {
        d.resolve(i, r);
    }, function(/*…*/) {
        d.resolve();
    });
    return d.promise();
});
$.when.apply($, calls).then(function() {
    var data = {};
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++)
        data[arguments[i][0]] = arguments[i][1];
    do_something(data);
});
```

Comment: I don't want all data. if one of query has no data then I don't show it. How to get around this.  always still doesn't work .

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the second parameter of `deferred.then()` ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)):

```
$.when.apply($, calls).then(function() {
    do_something(data);
}, function() {
    // something failed
});
```

If you want to call the same callback regardless of successes and failures, use `deferred.always()` ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/)):

```
$.when.apply($, calls).always(function() {
    do_something(data);
});
```

It is also worth reading the [`jQuery.when()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), which explains the aggregation when multiple deferred objects are passed.

Comment: is there a way to make do_something(data); execute no matter if it failed or not.

Comment: yeah, you can put the function in both the closures

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm just slightly lazy to put the functions in both.

Comment: @user2581550: Yep, use the `always` method.

Answer (score 2):

As jQuery docs the `.then` function takes two (or three) arguments in your case `deferred.then( doneCallbacks, failCallbacks )`

So you need to specify the second function to handle the failing request.

i.e.

```
$.when.apply($,calls).then(function() {
    alerT('ok');
}, function() {
    alert('fail');
});
```

Here a simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rrMwr/

Hope this helps